# High load average (over 2.0) on an idle machine

Tags: linux, load-average

I've this server which is basically idle, and yet has a high load average.

- Hardware : 4 processor PowerPC
- Over 4GB of *free* RAM
- Top says CPUs are 99.9% idle
- Virtually no disk I/O
- Debian Squeeze, default install except I'm using ext4

Here's the output of a few commands :

**uname -a**

```
Linux box 2.6.32-5-powerpc64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 02:01:42 UTC 2011 ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

**top**

```
top - 14:08:57 up  1:58,  1 user,  load average: 2.68, 2.45, 2.29
Tasks: 105 total,   1 running, 104 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4987256k total,  4965484k used,    21772k free,    16540k buffers
Swap: 24414028k total,        0k used, 24414028k free,  4781172k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2606 myself    20   0  3276 1340 1076 R    0  0.0   0:00.62 top
    1 root      20   0  2560  844  740 S    0  0.0   0:00.65 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
```

**uptime**

```
 14:09:23 up  1:58,  1 user,  load average: 2.54, 2.43, 2.28
```

**iostat -d 2 -m**

```
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sda               1.50         0.00         0.02          0          0
```

**free -m**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4870       4853         17          0         16       4669
-/+ buffers/cache:        167       4702
Swap:        23841          0      23841
```

**ps axf**

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/0]
    4 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S      0:00  \_ [watchdog/0]
    6 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/1]
    7 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
    8 ?        S      0:00  \_ [watchdog/1]
    9 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/2]
   10 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/2]
   11 ?        S      0:00  \_ [watchdog/2]
   12 ?        S      0:00  \_ [migration/3]
   13 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/3]
   14 ?        S      0:00  \_ [watchdog/3]
   15 ?        S      0:00  \_ [events/0]
   16 ?        S      0:00  \_ [events/1]
   17 ?        S      0:00  \_ [events/2]
   18 ?        S      0:00  \_ [events/3]
   19 ?        S      0:00  \_ [cpuset]
   20 ?        S      0:00  \_ [khelper]
   21 ?        S      0:00  \_ [netns]
   22 ?        S      0:00  \_ [async/mgr]
   23 ?        S      0:00  \_ [pm]
   24 ?        S      0:00  \_ [sync_supers]
   25 ?        S      0:00  \_ [bdi-default]
   26 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/0]
   27 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/1]
   28 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/2]
   29 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kintegrityd/3]
   30 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kblockd/0]
   31 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kblockd/1]
   32 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kblockd/2]
   33 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kblockd/3]
   38 ?        S      0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
   39 ?        S      0:04  \_ [kswapd0]
   40 ?        SN     0:00  \_ [ksmd]
   41 ?        S      0:00  \_ [aio/0]
   42 ?        S      0:00  \_ [aio/1]
   43 ?        S      0:00  \_ [aio/2]
   44 ?        S      0:00  \_ [aio/3]
   45 ?        S      0:00  \_ [crypto/0]
   46 ?        S      0:00  \_ [crypto/1]
   47 ?        S      0:00  \_ [crypto/2]
   48 ?        S      0:00  \_ [crypto/3]
  134 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ksuspend_usbd]
  135 ?        S      0:00  \_ [kmmcd]
  137 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ata/0]
  138 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ata/1]
  139 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ata/2]
  140 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ata/3]
  141 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ata_aux]
  142 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
  143 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
  144 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
  145 ?        S      0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_3]
  150 ?        S      0:00  \_ [khubd]
  174 ?        S      0:00  \_ [usbhid_resumer]
  227 ?        D      0:00  \_ [kwindfarm]
  239 ?        S      0:00  \_ [jbd2/sda3-8]
  240 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  241 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  242 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  243 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  424 ?        S      0:00  \_ [nouveau/0]
  425 ?        S      0:00  \_ [nouveau/1]
  426 ?        S      0:00  \_ [nouveau/2]
  427 ?        S      0:00  \_ [nouveau/3]
  459 ?        S      0:00  \_ [phy0]
  474 ?        S      0:00  \_ [flush-8:0]
  493 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ttm_swap]
  588 ?        S      0:00  \_ [bluetooth]
  635 ?        S      0:00  \_ [firewire_sbp2]
  693 ?        S      0:00  \_ [jbd2/sda5-8]
  694 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  695 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  696 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  697 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
 1694 ?        S      0:02  \_ [jbd2/sdb1-8]
 1695 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
 1696 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
 1697 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
 1698 ?        S      0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
    1 ?        Ss     0:00 init [2]  
  303 ?        S<s    0:00 udevd --daemon
  368 ?        S<     0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
 1385 ?        S<     0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
  929 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c4
  998 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
 1042 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
 1255 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
 1286 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
 1287 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
 1288 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
 1289 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
 1290 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
 1300 ?        Ss     0:00 dhclient -v -pf /var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
 1384 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
 2113 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2116 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2118 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2119 ?        Sl     0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2577 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Comment: do you have processes in the D state?

Comment: Nope. See the output of "ps axf"...

Comment: uname -a please... I need to know what kernel is.

Comment: It's a kernel problem. Either the kernel itself or a driver module is what is causing your issue. The exact one that is causing this may be hard to track down, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to upgrade/downgrade your kernel. Are several problems with the sheduler on different kernels:

1. http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail//linux/kernel/1010.1/02354.html
2. http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1169420

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Thing is, I'm running Debian stable, so I find it weird that such a noticeable bug could have slept through

Comment: It seems it appears only sometimes in some hardware configurations ... is very hard to detect such bugs.

Comment: Agree. Considering your arch.

Comment: Agree as well, though I'll also add that if your system's performance isn't impacted you may want to play "Ignore it and it will go away" with this -- Definitely report the issue to Debian and see if they can help get a fix into the main kernel tree though.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Ubuntu on my Quad G5, and I started noticing the exact same issue as well with 2.6.35-28-powerpc64-smp (kernel from Ubuntu 10.10).  My userland is up-to-date with Ubuntu 11.04, but the kernel is from 10.10 due to bugs in the newer kernel.

Running top in batch mode, the only thing I ever see in wait is kwindfarm.  Run 'top -b -i' for a while... do you see the same thing?  My hunch is that kwindfarm is the problem, but I don't want to go messing with kwindfarm and cause the fans to turn on full blast which would annoy/confuse my officemate since I'm remote right now.

Here are my list of suspect kernel modules ... try removing them and seeing if the problem goes away:

windfarm_smu_sensors     8567  1 
windfarm_smu_controls     7645  8 
windfarm_pm112         17416  0 
windfarm_smu_sat        8512  9 windfarm_pm112,[permanent]
windfarm_max6690_sensor     5628  1 
windfarm_lm75_sensor     6083  1 
windfarm_pid            3577  1 windfarm_pm112
windfarm_cpufreq_clamp     3829  1 
windfarm_core          16091  7 windfarm_smu_sensors,windfarm_smu_controls,windfarm_pm112,windfarm_smu_sat,windfarm_max6690_sensor,windfarm_lm75_sensor,windfarm_cpufreq_clamp

EDIT: This is the likely suspect.  A bit more googling turned up this thread from lkml:
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/860721

Comment: That is very interesting. However your LKML thread is really old, so I doubt this is it since I hadn't this issue in the previous Debian version (which had a kernel more recent than your link). Out of curiosity, what's that bug in the newer kernel ?

Comment: The new kernel bug I am referring to is in these two reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ports-meta/+bug/739913 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/714165

Comment: Your info seems to indicate that it is kwindfarm causing the load.  What kernel did you have in which you didn't see this problem?  Does it go away when you unload the windfarm modules?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and the culprit is the watchdog module you have enabled. I'm assuming it's a software watchdog, rather than a hardware one; and in theory, it's a nice idea, but in practice it's totally useless. if you really need a watchdog, get a hardware one; one that can actually reboot the box if needed, since a software one will stop working if the box freezes/panics.